# Email service that sends and receives all emails in domain (including wildcards)

Tags: gmail, email

I own a couple of domains which have numerous functional accounts all managed by me. So I'd like a way to log in once, see all incoming mails, and send from any username in this domain. (Ideally replies would default to the same email that was sent to.)

I know:
* GMail and many other services have catch-all settings, so *receiving* all emails is easy.
* GMail does support aliases and alternative from addresses. The problem with these is they must be individually added and confirmed. That's tedious. As the domain owner, I want to be able to just send from any arbitrary email without jumping through hoops.

Answer (score 2):

[FastMail](http://www.fastmail.fm) allows you to create a "wildcard" personality. When you select this personality when composing a message, you get a From: field in the compose window where you can set any address you like (within that domain, of course).

*Disclaimer: I work for FastMail.*